# json object modification within loop is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have json object return from the web service. 
Web service Object :

```
var seriesData = [{
    feederId: "PTS113T",
    businessEventCode: "LowVoltage",
    servicePointEventCount: 6,
    startDayID: 20130812,
}, {
    feederId: "PTS113T",
    businessEventCode: "HighVoltage",
    servicePointEventCount: 2,
    startDayID: 20130812,
}, {
    feederId: "PTS113T",
    businessEventCode: "LowVoltage",
    servicePointEventCount: 7,
    startDayID: 20130814,
}, {
    feederId: "PTS113T",
    businessEventCode: "HighVoltage",
    servicePointEventCount: 5,
    startDayID: 20130815,
}];
```

I want to modified that object into..

I have `startDayID` for every `startDayID` there will be two value or single value for `businessEventCode: "LowVoltage"`, or `businessEventCode: "HighVoltage",`

Want to :

```
var seriesData = [{
    feederId: "PTS113T",
    servicePointEventLowCount: 6,
    servicePointEventHighCount: 2,
    startDayID: 20130812,
}, {
    feederId: "PTS113T",
    servicePointEventLowCount: 7,
    startDayID: 20130814,
}, {
    feederId: "PTS113T",
    servicePointEventHighCount: 5,
    startDayID: 20130815,
}];
```

What i am doing :

```
if (seriesData) {
    var mockdata = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i += 2) {
        var data = {};
        //data.feederId = seriesData[i].feederId;
        if ((seriesData[i].startDayID) == (seriesData[i + 1].startDayID)) {
            data.feederId = seriesData[i].feederId;
            data.servicePointEventLowCount = seriesData[i].servicePointEventCount;
            data.servicePointEventHighCount = seriesData[i + 1].servicePointEventCount;
            data.startDayID = seriesData[i].startDayID;
        } else {
            data.feederId = seriesData[i].feederId;
            data.startDayID = seriesData[i].startDayID;

            if (seriesData[i].businessEventCode == 'LowVoltage') {
                data.servicePointEventLowCount = seriesData[i].servicePointEventCount;
                data.servicePointEventHighCount = 0;
            } else {
                data.servicePointEventHighCount = seriesData[i].servicePointEventCount;
                data.servicePointEventLowCount = 0;
            }

       }
        mockdata.push(data);
    }
```

Comment: Looks alright. How does the mockdata array look after loop has executed?

Comment: @springbo It is not displaying second last value... json value can be in any format so i cant compare i and i+2 value.. I guess u understood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this.

```
var mockdata = [];

// for check whether startDayID exist
//and temporary storage for data relative key(startDayID) 
var mockDataKeyMap ={}; 

for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length; i ++) {
    var item = seriesData[i];
    var key = item.startDayID;

    var data = null;

    if(!mockDataKeyMap[key]){

        // startDayID do not exist create new
        data = {};

        // save for get after (below else sentence)
        mockDataKeyMap[key] = data; 

        // push into
        mockdata.push(data);

        // set default info
        data.feederId = item.feederId;
        data.startDayID = item.startDayID;

    }else{

        // if startDayID exist get data from map
        data= mockDataKeyMap[key]; 
    }

    if (item.businessEventCode === 'LowVoltage') {
        data.servicePointEventLowCount = item.servicePointEventCount;
    } 
    if (item.businessEventCode === 'HighVoltage') {
        data.servicePointEventHighCount = item.servicePointEventCount;
    }
}
```

it is very dangerous to use `"i+=2"`

Your `seriesData` always do not have couple of data `LowVoltage` and `HighVoltage`.

Then check all data `i++`

Then check only key is already exist or not

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
for (var i = 0; i < seriesData.length-1; i += 2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

as per your loop for the last run you will not have `seriesData[i + 1].startDayID` better check this condition while processing.